# How do I create an instance of a class that is namespace within another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-for

```
resources :recipes do
  resource :like, module: :recipes
  resources :comments, only: [:new, :create, :show, :index], module: :recipes
end

recipe_comments GET    /recipes/:recipe_id/comments(.:format) recipes/comments#index
               POST   /recipes/:recipe_id/comments(.:format)  recipes/comments#create

Comments are in /recipes/:id
Recipe Controller

def show
   @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
   @comment = @recipe.comments.new
   @clean_recipe = Sanitizer.new(@recipe)
end

Recipes::CommentsController

Theres a before action that finds recipe.

 def create
    @comment = @recipe.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to recipes_path
    end
end
```

I've done

```
   form_for([@article,@comment]) and form_for [@article,Comment.new]
```

and still the comment isn't persisted. I am wondering because of the module namespace, do I have to do something different?

Answer (score 1):

Add `logger.info 'I am inside create action in comments controller'` inside the create action. If you see this logger message in the rails console, then the create action gets called. It means your routes are defined correctly, your form is using the right form helper.

Answer (score 0):

the correct format is form_for([@recipe, @comment]) however, I had a length validation in my comment model which was failing to pass. I set too_short and too_long messages, however they didn't show up, which further confused me